# ggplot 2: generate one separate box plot per column

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to generate many individual plots, each plotting the level of one single gene (=column) for each cell (=row). In the code I also have two subsets of "cell", based on whether each cell has a value of >0 for gene1 or not (this is handled with dplyr).

My attempt below plots the values for all genes/columns in one single pdf plot, once. Any advice on how I can alter my code to generate one plot per gene/column?

Dataset:

```
          gene1      gene2      gene3      gene4      gene5
cell_1   0.0000   0.279204  25.995400  46.171700  94.234100
cell_2   0.0000  23.456000  77.339800 194.241000 301.234000
cell_3   2.0000  13.100000  45.309200   0.776565   0.000000
cell_4   0.0000  10.500000 107.508000   3.032500   0.000000
cell_5   3.0000   0.000000   0.266139   0.762981 123.371000
```

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

#Loop making many single box plots

  df3 <- df2 %>% as.data.frame %>% mutate(Cell= rownames(.), positive = df2$gene1>0) %>% 
    gather(., key= gene, value="value", -Cell,-positive) %>% 
    mutate( absolute= abs(value), logabs= log(absolute+1))

  for (i in unique(df3$gene)) {
    geneplot <- df3 %>% ggplot(., aes(x=gene, y=logabs, fill=positive)) +
          geom_boxplot() +
          xlab("Gene") + ylab("Expression level (TPM log)") + 
          theme_classic(base_size = 14, base_family = "Helvetica") +
          theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=14)) + 
          theme(axis.title.y=element_text(size=14, face="bold")) + 
          theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=14)) +
          theme(axis.title.x=element_text(size=14, face="bold")) + 
          scale_fill_brewer(palette="Pastel1")
   print(geneplot)
   ggsave(sprintf("%s.png", df3$gene))

   dev.off()

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gene1<-c(0.0000, 0.0000, 2.0000, 0.0000, 3.0000)
gene2<-c(0.279204, 23.456000, 13.100000 , 10.500000, 3.0000)
gene3<-c(25.995400, 77.339800, 45.309200, 107.508000, 0.266139)
gene4<-c(46.171700, 194.241000, 0.776565, 3.032500, 0.762981)
gene5<-c(94.234100, 301.234000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 3.0000)
df<-data.frame(gene1, gene2, gene3,gene4,gene5)

df <- df %>% 
    as.data.frame %>% 
    mutate(Cell= rownames(.), positive = df$gene1>0) %>% 
    gather(., key= gene, value="value", -Cell,-positive) %>% 
    mutate( absolute= abs(value), logabs= log(absolute+1))

ggplot(data= df , aes(x=gene, y=logabs, fill=positive))+
    geom_boxplot()+facet_wrap(~ gene)
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

I'm not exactly sure what the poster is asking but here are a couple interpretations:

The actual data has additional genes with values of one, therefore, using `facet_wrap(~ gene)` creates an additional unnecessary plot like in the following:

```
gene1<-c(0.0000, 0.0000, 2.0000, 0.0000, 3.0000)
gene2<-c(0.279204, 23.456000, 13.100000 , 10.500000, 3.0000)
gene3<-c(25.995400, 77.339800, 45.309200, 107.508000, 0.266139)
gene4<-c(46.171700, 194.241000, 0.776565, 3.032500, 0.762981)
gene5<-c(94.234100, 301.234000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 3.0000)
gene6<-c(0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)
df<-data.frame(gene1, gene2, gene3,gene4,gene5, gene6)

df <- df %>% 
  as.data.frame %>% 
  mutate(Cell= rownames(.), positive = df$gene1>0) %>% 
  gather(., key= gene, value="value", -Cell,-positive) %>% 
  mutate( absolute= abs(value), logabs= log(absolute+1))

ggplot(data= df , aes(x=gene, y=logabs, fill=positive))+
  geom_boxplot()+facet_wrap(~ gene)
```

[image]

To avoid that, simply simply run

```
df<-filter(df, value>0)

ggplot(data= df , aes(x=gene, y=logabs, fill=positive))+
  geom_boxplot()+facet_wrap(~ gene)
```

To get:

[image]

If that's not your concern my apologies. Perhaps it's that you want to get rid of the breaks for individual genes with no values, like in the following as  @Huub Hoofs pointed out. To accomplish that, as  Huub Hoofs suggest, try the following:

```
ggplot(data= df , aes(x=gene, y=logabs, fill=positive))+
    geom_boxplot()+facet_grid(~ gene, scales = "free")
```

[image]

OR

```
ggplot(data= df , aes(x=gene, y=logabs, fill=positive))+
    geom_boxplot(aes(1))+facet_wrap(~ gene)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But: If I would have a large amount of genes (which I do in my sharp dataset), this solution would not work since each boxplot would become very skinny or each diagram would become very wide since the boxplots that aren't shown in each diagram still have their empty slots there.. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Scales = "free" ? Or aes(x=1)

Comment: These last two options is what I want to achieve! Unfortunately, when I put in my full dataset (containing somewhere around 1000 "gene" columns) the whole thing does not fit in one single page. I end up seeing just tho "headline" part of the diagram. Is there any way in ggplot to split the facet_wraps on various pages, or would I need to go back to my (not functioning) for loop solution?

Comment: I actually managed to solve my additional problem now! I stopped using the facet_wrap function, and instead loaded the ggplus package and used the facet_multiple function. I added this row of code:

facet_multiple(plot = p, facets = 'gene', ncol = 4, nrow = 4)

Comment: @Galaffer, good to hear you solved it! Quick question, how is ``facet_multiple`` different than ``facet_wrap`` (in terms of your desired output, I know it can print to multiple pages which wrap cannot do, which is the whole point)? I tried that ``facet_multiple`` with identical results...

Comment: @Cyrus Mohammadian, From what I read, I think the whole point is to be able to print multiple page pdfs. Since I generate around 1000-2500 diagrams in one run, I cannot keep them on a single page.

Comment: @Galaffer ahhhhh I seee! Thanks! Yes perfect for ``facet_multiple``. Good luck!

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian, Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @Galaffer no problem!